# Credential Caching issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a static helper method that I wrap around SMTPClient to send email.

I am storing the SMTP authentication in the web.config -> in the default location that System.Net namespace objects look for.

I am passing the credentials to the SMTPClient, because I want to run my password decryption on the password before the SMTPClient uses this.

The issue that I'm encountering here is - when I run this once, the password is stored somehwere as "decrypted" somehow in the cache. When I try and run this method a second time in the same session, I get an error, because it's trying to decrypt a password that was already decrypte the first time it was ran. Any ideas?

```
    public static void SendEmail(MailMessage mailMessage)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();
        nc = (NetworkCredential)smtpClient.Credentials;
        nc.Password = Tools.Decrypt(nc.Password);
        smtpClient.Credentials = nc;
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        nc = null;
        smtpClient.Credentials = null;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NetworkCredentials is a class you are passing a reference of to your nc variable this means when you decrypt the password you are decrypting it on the original object.

You either need to clone the object or only do this once when your application starts.

Comment: Thank you. Why is it staying in memory if I am using it in a static?

Comment: Would it be possible to show me a brief sample of how to do this in Global.asax? While still being able to use it from a static?

Comment: Internal to the SmtpClient object the Credentials are set via a static property. So although your SmtpClient is instantiated each request the Credentials are populated using the same static object.

This means all SmtpClient instances are actually using the same static instance of NetworkCredentials. This property keeps the same object reference for the entire lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit hacky but just putting

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();
nc = (NetworkCredential)smtpClient.Credentials;
nc.Password = Tools.Decrypt(nc.Password);
smtpClient.Credentials = nc;
smtpClient = null;
```

in you global.asax might do it. And then having

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
smtpClient = null;
```

in you static method, though I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution.

Update: You could probably try using SmtpNetworkElement and updating the password on this in the global.asax - I think as long as you do this before you use SmtpClient it may work.